# how to send a notification to millions of android devices in php using GCM

Tags: php, curl, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am a new developer of Android app. I am sending notifications from PHP code to the android devices using GCM. I made an array of all device ids and send but the problem is when i send more than a thousand devices . I found internal server error. My code is below

```
function _send_notification($registatoin_ids = '', $message = '') {
    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
        'data' => $message,
    );
    //pr($fields);
    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . $this->GOOGLE_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Connection: keep-alive',
        'Keep-Alive: 300'
    );
    $ch = curl_init();
    // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECT_ONLY, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10000); // drop connection after 10000 seconds
    // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
    // Execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }
    // Close connection
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result; //exit;
}
```

Please help me out

Answer (score 4):

The maximum number of registration ids you can send is 1,000. You'll need to break it into multiple curl calls with groupings of 1k registration ids each.

```
function _send_notification($registration_ids = '', $message = '') {
    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
    $groups = array_chunk($registration_ids, 1000);

    foreach($groups as $group) {
        $fields = array(
            'registration_ids' => $group,
            'data' => $message,
        );
        // ...
        // rest of your curl code
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ... I was doing this still there is a time out problem . If i reduce to 250 then it will work. But if I have more than 1 millions of users then there will be the same time out problem