# Php button push notification android

Tags: php, android, notifications, push

I'm trying to implement push notification but I'm a little bit lost.
I just want to have a button in php and when I click it, a notification appear in all devices telling the users something like: "A new image is available in the web".

I read the GCM documentation but I'm not sure how to start.

I see that in some examples the users have to send their emails in order to register their "sender id"? it is necessary? I want the user don't have to register anywhere.

Can someone help me to start or give me a quick tutorial?

Thank's for all.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use curl to call the GCM, you can find examples like this all over SO, for example : [how to send a notification to millions of android devices in php using GCM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23113250/how-to-send-a-notification-to-millions-of-android-devices-in-php-using-gcm) (first one that came up in a search)

And of course you will need the registration id's otherwise GCM doesznt know which device to send the notification to.

Comment: If i want to send a notification to all the devices who has the app installed i need this registration id?

Comment: @PabloGarcia maybe learning how to use google could benefit you more in this case : http://rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2013/11/android-push-notification-google-cloud.html

Answer (score 0):

The solution is not so simple. You should at least use some package dedicated to this specific service. Also, you should read something about [what push notifications are](http://searchmobilecomputing.techtarget.com/definition/push-notification).

There are many services out there you can use to interface yourself with this specific kind of service.

Take a look to [this service](https://github.com/pubnub/php) to get a first idea about the entire mechanism. Remember that you have to subscribe to a push service provider for every platform you want to use. For example the [Apple Push Notification Service](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html), or [Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) by Google.

Hope it's a good start for you.

Comment: apple push notifiactions when the question is tagged android and the question clearly reads GCM ?

Comment: I tried to give him a more complete overview of the mechanism. Also, many PHP packages out there offer the possibility to enable both services in no-time. It's always good to know something more. Not the same for knowing something less.

Comment: fair enough, but there are 2 sides to that coin, alot of information can get people lost even more